# Not all paths return a value

Tags: c#, syntax-error

So i'm getting an error in my program with my Google Speech API. The error is "Not all paths return a value" as the title suggest.
Here is the code (2 peices)(Same error)

```
 public static SpeechInputResult ProcessFlacFile(string FlacFileName, int BIT_RATE = DEFAULT_BIT_RATE, string language = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE, uint maxresults = 1)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1" + "&client=" + client + "&lang=" + language + "&maxresults=" + maxresults + "&pfilter=0");
            FileStream fStream = new FileStream(FlacFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.Timeout = 60000;
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "audio/x-flac; rate=8000";
            //bitrate must = .flac file
            request.UserAgent = client;
            FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(FlacFileName);
            long numbytes = fInfo.Length;
            byte[] data = null;
            using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(FlacFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                data = new byte[fstream.Length];
            fStream.Read(data, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fStream.Length));
            fStream.Close();
            using (Stream wrStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                wrStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                dynamic resp = response.GetResponseStream();
                if (resp != null)
                {
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp);
                    MessageBox.Show(sr.ReadToEnd());
                    resp.Close();
                    resp.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ee)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and 2nd piece here:

```
            public class Hypothesis
        {
            public string utterance;
            public double confidence = -1.0d;//-1 = No Value
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return "'" +utterance + "'" + ((confidence == -1) ? "" : "@" + confidence);
            }
            public List<Hypothesis> hypotheses = new List<Hypothesis>();

            public Hypothesis getBestHypothesis()
            {
                if (hypotheses.Count() <=0)
                    return null;
                Hypothesis H = hypotheses[0];
                foreach (Hypothesis h in hypotheses)
                {
                    if (h.confidence>=H.confidence)
                    {
                        H = h;
                    }
                    return H;
                }
            }
```

Both code have the same error and it only seems to happen if I a certain variable name to be the same name as another variable (FlacFileName, to be exact). If you guys could tell me why this is happening that would be awesome thanks!

Comment: Well, it means that no all execution paths in your code return a value.

Comment: There's no `return` statement in the first function.

Comment: So essentially add a return statement to the end of the first if statement in the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method signature

```
public static SpeechInputResult ProcessFlacFile(string FlacFileName, int BIT_RATE = DEFAULT_BIT_RATE, string language = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE, uint maxresults = 1)
```

states you will be returning a `SpeechInputResult` but you have no `return` statement.

You should either change the signature to `void` or actually return a value.

In the second instance, you need a return statement after the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Like everyone mentioned, add a `return` statement to the end of the first method. Just a `return null;` or whatever's appropriate in your situation. Actually, you have no other `return` statements in that method at all, so it's not a "not all paths return a value" situation like the second... you may just want to change the signature from `SpeechInputResult` to `void`.

---

In the second method, it *seems* like you have your bases covered, because:

- You're returning `null` if `hypotheses` is empty and
- You're returning the `hypotheses` with the largest "confidence" if it's not empty

But the compiler isn't smart enough to see that. Try moving `return null;` to the end. The only way you'll make it there is if there are no elements in the list and the `foreach` loop doesn't run.

```
public Hypothesis getBestHypothesis()
{
    if (hypotheses.Any())
    {
        Hypothesis H = hypotheses[0];

        foreach (Hypothesis h in hypotheses)
        {
            if (h.confidence >= H.confidence)
            {
                H = h;
            }
            return H;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

Also, that whole second method could be reduced (with the help of LINQ):

```
return hypotheses.OrderByDescending(x => x.confidence).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

i find that in your code you have to return `SpeechInputResult` but there is no where you are using return statement. 
It is preferred that you use `return SpeechInputResult` in your code

other wise put your function as below if your are not willing to return anything to it.

```
public static void ProcessFlacFile(string FlacFileName, int BIT_RATE = DEFAULT_BIT_RATE, string language = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE, uint maxresults = 1)
```

you can use void instead of the class `SpeechInputResult` as in the above code if you want to be it without the error in this case.

in the second piece of code you only instantiated the code. ie declared and directly used it
you must have something assigned to the object you created so that you can perform operation in the foreach.

in this case `hypotheses` doesnt have any thing inside it.

Also you have written return statement inside the foreach loop where as the focus will never go inside the foreach loop.

First you assign something to `hypotheses` so that it has value in it and then perform actions.

Answer (score 1):

First block of code does not have any return statement. In the second code block , put a dummy return statement outside the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

In your first method, you declared in signature that, it will be returning instance of type`SpeechInputResult`, while you are not returning it from body.

And, in second method, you are returning from inside `foreach` loop, but what if your `hypotheses` list doesn't have any element? You should also be returning either a default value from outside the `foreach` loop or you should throw an exception if it isn't your expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`ProcessFlacFile` method in the above code should return a type `SpeechInputResult` object in all cases.

You can return the object after try and catch as

```
try
{
}
catch
{
}

return SpeechInputResultObj
```

or

return `SpeechInputResult` object in both `try` and `catch` statement

```
try
{
    ....
    return SpeechInputResultObj;
}

catch
{
    ....
    return SpeechInputResultObj;
}
```

Comment: I just had to put return null; at the end of catch and the it worked!